# Having trouble inverting a simple math equation using logarithms in Python

Tags: python, numpy, math, logarithm, algebra

After trying to reverse a very simple math formula for the past day, I've given up after bumping my head against `scipy.special.lambertw` -- which might not even be the correct place to be looking.

I have the following equation:

```py
import numpy

# The following == 70.03
np.sqrt(np.log(742) * 742)
```

I'm trying to invert that equation -- where inputing `70.03` would equal `742`.

Here was my current attempt after playing around with an algebra solver and Wolfram Alpha:

```py
from scipy.special import lambertw

np.power(np.power(np.e, lambertw(70.03)), 2)
```

**This obviously produces an incorrect answer — but since algebra was so long ago, I'm basically lost as to how to produce a function that coverts `70.03` back into `742`.**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: wolframalpha says `f = lambda x: x ** 2/ lambertw(x ** 2)` btw there is no np.pow but np.power exists

Comment: but i dont have the mathematics to find what wolframalpha found, i hope you understand why `f` above is the inverse really

Comment: f(70.03) gives (742.008379366021+0j) for me

Comment: Wow, you solved it @athing! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it -- thanks so much!

Comment: fyi, `lambertw(x)`(`W()`) gives you the inverse of `xe^x` but you also can use it for `xlogx` since`xlogx` can be rewritten as `log(x)e^log(x)`  with the equality `x = e^log(x)`, so you get `ue^u` with `u=log(x)`. You should be able to work out the maths from there to  `e^W(x^2)` the identity `e^W(x)=x/W(x)` will get you to wolfram's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From WolframAlpha I get

```
from scipy.special import lambertw

f = lambda x: x ** 2 / lambertw(x ** 2)
```

as the inverse.

indeed

f(70.03) gives (742.008379366021+0j)

but i dont have the mathematics to find what wolframalpha found, i hope you understand why f above is the inverse really

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I thank you for the offer i hope it goes well for you